# Search Registry and create New-Item

Tags: powershell, while-loop, registry, new-item

I want to create a `New-Item`  in the registry with a pre check  what already exists.

This code

```
$items = get-item "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options" 
$items.Property -match "OPEN"
```

returns the following

```
OPEN
OPEN1
OPEN2
OPEN3
OPEN4
```

Now I know I need to create a `New-Item` with the name `OPEN5`, but how do I count through this? Maybe with a `While-Loop`?

Comment: You could do something like `for ($i = 0; $i -lt $items.Count; $i++ { # implementation code here }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most robust approach is to extract the embedded numbers, sort them numerically, and add `1` to the highest index to date:

```
$nextNdx = 1 +
  ([int[]] ($items.Property -match '^OPEN' -replace '\D') | Sort-Object)[-1]
```

- `$items.Property -match '^OPEN' -replace '\D'` returns all property names that start with `OPEN` and removes all non-digit characters from them (`-replace '\D'`).
- `[int[]]` converts the resulting "number strings" to actual numbers (`[int]`); note that casting `''` or `$null` to `[int]` in PowerShell yields `0`.
- `Sort-Object` sorts these numbers, and `[-1]` grabs the last number from the resulting array, i.e., the highest number.

---

The above is convenient, but not fast, due to use of the pipeline and the `Sort-Object` cmdlet.

If you want to avoid the pipeline for performance reasons:

```
$indices = [int[]] ($items.Property -match '^OPEN' -replace '\D')
[Array]::Sort($indices) # sort in place
$nextNdx = 1 + $indices[-1]
```